# Community site error

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, site-template, community-site

After installing SharePoint 2013 Foundation, fully patch it and installed pt-br language pack, I can't create a site collection from the "Community" site template. I get an error stating that:

> there's already a list or library with that name

Has anyone seen this problem? Is there a workaround for it?

Answer (score 0):

I've had some problems with the Style Library. Not sure if it's the case, but if for some reason the site collection exists and has that library, you can try deleting it.
You can also check the ULS logs for specifics.